# How to call oracle r12 stored procedure with yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii2

I have created a procedure in oracle R12, like following, but i cannot get the result in YII2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproctest(username IN OUT varchar2) is
encPass varchar2(255);
BEGIN
      select 
      aa.ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD into encPass from
      fnd_user aa
      where aa.USER_NAME = username;
      username := encPass;
END;
```

It works fine when i execute it from PLSQL, but while executing it from yii2 it always shows 1. Following is the execution code:

```
$query=Yii::$app->dboracle->createCommand(
"declare
   UserName varchar2(255) := 'MY-USERNAME';
begin
    myproctest(UserName);
    dbms_output.put_line(UserName);
end;");
$data = $query->execute();
```

I have also tried following for execution:

```
$query=Yii::$app->dboracle->createCommand("CALL myproctest('TEST-USER')");     
$data = $query->execute();
```

But it shows following error:

> ORA-06577: output parameter not a bind variable

**I want to get the password field in a variable please help.**

Comment: I don't have an Oracle db to test against, but I expect you need to use Command::bindParam.  Something like: $query = Yii::$app->dboracle->createCommand("CALL myproctest(:username)"); $username = 'TEST-USER'; $query->bindParam('username', $username); $query->execute(); echo "encPass = $username";

Comment: This is also not working. On firefox its showing a message : The connection was reset and on chrome the message is: This site can’t be reached, and also i could not understand this part of your code: echo "encPass = $username";

Comment: Sounds like your (my) code is throwing an exception.  Check your php & web server error logs.  The echo statement was my way of saying I expect the stored proc call to replace the contents of $username with encPass.  Again, I have no Oracle db so can't provide much more direction, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you want to get value from oracle R12 procedure in PHP variable using YII2

> Create procedure in **Oracle R12** with **output variable** eg PWD in example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYPROCTEST (USERNAME VARCHAR2,PWD OUT VARCHAR2)  as
BEGIN
    --  YOUR QUERY(S) OR assign password as per your requirement 
    PWD:='YOUR RESPONSE STRING';  
end MYPROCTEST;
```

> Calling procedure using **YII2**

```
$sql="
    begin
        MYPROCTEST(:IN_VAR_TESTUSER,:OUT_VAR_PASSWORD);
    end;";
    
$query=Yii::$app->dbconnection->createCommand($sql,[':IN_VAR_TESTUSER'=>'TEST-USER']);
$query->bindParam(':OUT_VAR_PASSWORD', $RETURN_PASSWORD,\PDO::PARAM_STR|\PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,4000);
$query->execute();
```

> You will get result in **$RETURN_PASSWORD**